# Wordpress plugin Contact Form 7 change layout with help of any plugin

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Is there any plugin in Wordpress that helps a user to manage form layout easily? Wordpress plugin Contact Form 7 changes layout with help of any plugin.

[i have got one plugin here that works fine.](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-skins-contact-form-7/)

Are there any more similar plugins?

Comment: Did the below work out for you?

Answer (score 2):

The tools built in to Contact Form 7 will allow you to modify the way your form looks. It all really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

The following code for example, will produce a form that is wrapped with the Twitter Bootstrap classes.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Name*</label>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      [text* your-name class:form-control id:name placeholder "Your name"] 
    </div>

    <label for="email" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Email*</label>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      [email* your-email class:form-control id:email placeholder "Your email"] 
    </div>

    <label for="contactnumber" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Number*</label>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      [tel* contact-number class:form-control id:contactnumber placeholder "Your contact number"] 
    </div>

    <label for="message" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Message*</label>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      [textarea* your-message class:form-control id:message placeholder "Your message"] 
    </div>
</div>
```

This can be added directly into Contact Form 7, without any additional plugins, but as I mentioned, we'll need a better idea of what you're trying to achieve.